# Passing the servername/Ldap inside "DirectoryEntry" Vs "PrincipalContext"

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, ldap, .net-4.6

I have this action method inside my ASP.NET MVC-5 .net 4.6:-

```
public ActionResult UsersInfo2()
        {

            List<DomainContext> results = new List<DomainContext>();
            try
            {
                // create LDAP connection object  

                DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = createDirectoryEntry();
                string ADServerName = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServerName"];
                string ADusername = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADUserName"];
                string ADpassword = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADPassword"];
                using (var context = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://mydomain.com:389/DC=mydomain,DC=com", ADusername, ADpassword))
                using (var search = new DirectorySearcher(context))
                { 
                            SearchResult r = search.FindOne();
                       
                            ResultPropertyCollection fields = r.Properties;

                            foreach (String ldapField in fields.PropertyNames)
                                string temp;
                                foreach (Object myCollection in fields[ldapField])
                                    temp = String.Format("{0,-20} : {1}",
                                                   ldapField, myCollection.ToString());
                            }
                }
                
               using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com", ADusername, ADpassword))
                {

                 bool isvalid  = context.ValidateCredentials("*******", "****************");

                }
                        
                        
                        
                        }
                        
                        
            

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught:\n\n" + e.ToString());
            }
            return View(results);

        }
```

so after around one day of testing i realize that for the `DirectoryEntry` I need to pass the server/ldap as follow `("LDAP://mydomain.com:389/DC=mydomain,DC=com", ADusername, ADpassword))` , while for the `PrincipalContext` we need to pass it as follow:- `(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com", ADusername, ADpassword))`.. so i can not pass the ldap inside the `PrincipalContext` nor the servrname only inside the  `DirectoryEntry` .. so is this the case? or i am doing things wrongly ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

The [`System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement?view=netframework-4.6)  (`PrincipalContext`, `UserPrincipal`, etc.) was created to simplify things. However, it just uses the [`System.DirectoryServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices?view=netframework-4.6) namespace (`DirectoryEntry`, etc.) in the background. (except for `ValidateCredentials`, [which uses `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/Context.cs#L148)).

I prefer to always use `DirectoryEntry` and friends because it gives me more control over performance. That's something I wrote an article about: [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply. but what about the passing the servername vs ldap string? are those suppose to work as i mentioned?

Comment: Yes. `PrincipalContext` will create the LDAP path for you.

Comment: Note that for `DirectoryEntry`, you could just use `LDAP://mydomain.com`, since port 389 is the default, and it will use the root of the domain by default too. You only need to specify the DN if you want something other than the root of the domain. See the documentation for [LDAP ADsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/ldap-adspath)